# How can I open a lxterminal with a script running in it?

Tags: terminal

How can I open a lxterminal with a script running in it?

Hello,

I want to open lxterminal and have a a script running in it?

Example:

I have a simple bash script that just shows the filesystem using ls.

The name of the script is files.sh

lxterminal --command=/home/pi/files.sh

The terminal starts but immediately closes again. How can I make it stay open?

Vesa

Comment: Make the terminal read one character before it exits using `lxterminal --command=/home/pi/files.sh; read -n 1 -s`. [Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/868814/734531)

Comment: Hello @codell. It doesn't work, it just opens a terminal, runs the script and closes the terminal again. I want to keep it open and be able to input to the command prompt.

Comment: @CodeIt : And both of the answers don't work according to asker :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass only a single program or executable script file to the `--command` option. The reason for this is simple: there isn't any sub-shell ran implicitly that could parse a sequence of commands.

You have two options:

1. Add a command that waits for input at the end of your script. Then execute only your script with the `--command` option.
2. Run a shell explicitly with the `--command` option.

Like this:

```
lxterminal --command="/bin/bash -c '/home/pi/files.sh; read'"
```

**Edit:** How to allow input of new commands in the opened `lxterminal`.

Again this can be done in two ways. Either open yet another shell:

```
lxterminal --command="/bin/bash -c '/home/pi/files.sh; /bin/bash'"
```

Or - And this can be shell specific! - Run the script with `--init-file`:

```
lxterminal --command="/bin/bash --init-file /home/pi/files.sh"
```

Comment: The last oneliner almost works. I can see the output of the script in the lxterminal window and the window stays open but I cannot input anything which I would ideally like to be able to do. Any way to make it possible to do the same thing but still being able to input at a shell prompt after the script has finished running?

Comment: @Vesa well you didn't ask that initially :) Updated the answer.

Comment: It worked. You solved the problem Marek, congratulations and best wishes for the new year.

Comment: Whay have no one addressed the fact that lxterminal does not launch when command has spaces inside the quotes? For me, the only way to make this happen is to escape spaces with forward slash. Like so: `lxterminal --command="/bin/bash\ -c\ '/home/pi/files.sh;\ /bin/bash'"` (Tested on Ubuntu 18.10)

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk It launches for me just with the spaces and no escaping. I'm running debian 9, lxterminal 0.3.0. I have no idea what causes the different behavior in your case. Perhaps locale settings....

Comment: I ended up using `-e` option like so: `lxterminal -e /home/pi/files.sh... `. Works perfectly without escaping anything.

Comment: actually, the escape character is a backslash `\\`.   the path separator character is the forward slash `/`